# 502 bad gateway error with Stripe webhooks

Tags: payment-gateway, gateway, stripe-payments

I am getting 502 bad gateway error in webhooks for test stripe account. Whenever a payment related event is fired we are handling webhook in our application.
Sometime it works, but most of the time it throws 502 error for the same code.
In Stripe documentation it is mentioned that it is because of stripe server and is rare but in our application it is coming very frequently. 
We had tried debugging our code but there is no issue and the same webhook events work on retries.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately any HTTP 5xx error that is recorded by Stripe as a response on calling a webhook endpoint has to be debugged on your backend. A good thing to do is put in as much logging as possible in your webhook endpoint(s) and also record the event ids evt_xxx so that you can compare all Events that Stripe has sent you against what you processed and the outcomes in your backend.